# How can I get the name of a generic class programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I want to get the name of a class dynamically. I can use this:

```
public void RequestData<TResult>()
{
     var myName = typeof(TResult).Name;
}
```

Which works fine e.g. if `TResult` is of type `MyClass` then `myName` would equal `"MyClass"`

But if TResult is of type

```
List<MyClass>
```

I still want myName to equal "MyClass" ... at the moment it will be "List`1"

So if `TResult` is going to be of type `List` how can I programmatically know that it's a `List` and then pick out the name of the type of this list?

Comment: Check code in recent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791344/how-to-get-generic-list-concrete-type-not-its-interface - `GetGenericArguments` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be done with the help of a few methods on the [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Type.aspx).

```
public void RequestData<TResult>()
{
    Type type = typeof(TResult);
    string myName;
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
    {
        myName = type.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name;
    }
    else
    {
        myName = typeof(TResult).Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the 'leftmost' inner generic type with

```
public static Type GetInnermost(Type t)
{
    while(t.IsGenericType)
    {
        t = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }
    return t;
}
```

then you can do:

```
var myName = GetInnermost(typeof(TResult)).Name;
```

then e.g.

```
RequestData<List<IEnumerable<Task<IObserverable<string>>>();
```

will have a name of `String`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) method, which `returns an array of Type objects that represent the type arguments of a generic type or the type parameters of a generic type definition.` (MSDN).

For sample:

```
public void RequestData<TResult>()
{
     var myName = typeof(TResult).Name;
     var type = typeof(TResult)
     if (type.IsGenericType)
     {
         myName = type.GetGenericArguments().First().Name;
     }
}
```